# Is it possible to add billing permissions prgramatically in Android

Tags: android, optimization, in-app-purchase, android-manifest, android-permissions

I have two different apps with the same codebase, one is **paid** and another on is **free with IAB**.

The **Free** version of the app having IAB integrated and it requires Billing permissions and the **Paid** Version des not required this permission so I have to comment this permission every time while preparing the build.

So I am looking for any better solution so I can avoid this current process, so can I add this permission programmatically with respect to free and paid check.

Comment: Refer [this thing](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: This is for the Runtime permissions but billing permissions do not fall into critical permissions group

Comment: You can not give the billing permission at run time it is not possible bro. [Check out this](https://medium.com/@gabri.mariotti/why-billing-permission-is-not-required-at-runtime-7858a2a56ced).

Comment: Thank you @AndyDeveloper, do have any suggestion to better maintain one codebase to compile two apk.

Comment: As I suggest try to upload 2 different APK 1 is free and 2 is paid. As we seen on Google Play store. I also do the same thing for 2 application. it is easy to manage. OR you have to give permission in same APK. I don't think there will be any other way except these two.